# Windows Phone 7 emulator - won't run in a virtual machine, workarounds?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, windows-phone-7, virtual-machine, parallels

**Macbook Pro** 2011 i7 13". Mac OSX 10.6.7, **bootcamp partition running Windows 7**. Am running a 240GB SSD and 8GB ram, the computer is more than fast enough to run Visual Studio 2010 in a VM.

If I run Visual Studio from Bootcamp it works fine and develop my apps. Reboot into OSX and fire up the same partition using Parallels in either window or coherence mode I get the message:

**Windows Phone Emulator is doing a complete OS boot...."**

and the emulator, closes. I've found a few threads and posts about this:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/593422/windows-phone-emulator-shuts-down-computer
- http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68634/481915.aspx#481915
- [Windows phone 7 takes forever to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329645/windows-phone-7-takes-forever-to-deploy)

I understand it's not officially supported but if there is a workaround it would be amazing as **I'd prefer to "live" in Mac OSX and just use Windows for Office and Visual Studio.** I like this working model.

Any workarounds, any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 emulator on a VM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878307/windows-phone-7-emulator-on-a-vm)

Comment: Duplicate. There is no workaround as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other article, yeah looks like there is no workaround unfortunately. Will have to do my dev from Bootcamp

Comment: Actually it sounds like it works with VMware Fusion but is slow, I wonder if I can use Fusion from OSX over my bootcamp partition, it already has the Parallels tools installed, not sure if I should mess with it by also adding VM Ware Fusion...

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone Emulator is a virtual machine, and you can't run a virtual machine inside another one...

Answer (score 0):

Its not likely that you can do this as inside the emulator is Virtual PC, another virtual machine. It would be quite taxing to run a VM inside a VM.

Comment: The issue is nothing to do with taxing. The specs of my machine are blazingly fast, Visual Studio is flying with other projects, there is some incompatibility with the Windows Phone Emulator software I hope to workaround