# Setting WP7 Softwares on mac

Tags: windows, macos, windows-phone-7

I want to know can we install WP7 software on Mac machine.

I found that virtual machine is an option but Windows Phone emulator will not run from within a VM.

Another thing I found is Boot Camp software can be used to install window device drivers.
I want to know will this serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, virtual machine is not an option.

You need to dual boot your Mac with bootcamp. Through which it is possible to develop for WP7.

Comment: by using boot camp we need to restart every time  i want use wp7 tool, correct me if i am wrong. isn't there any other option

Comment: AFAIK, no other options, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605460/windows-phone-7-emulator-wont-run-in-a-virtual-machine-workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a virtual image to install Windows 7 and the Windows Phone Tools and SDK. If you are developing XNA app the emulator might not work. You need to make sure DirectX 10 is supported.

Hope this help.
Dani